# Как передать значение в следующий контролер?

Tags: ios, objective-c, index

Есть 2 кнопки в `ViewController`. В `NextViewController` нужно определить какая из кнопок была нажата и исходя из этого выбрать с каким массивом работать.

Пробовал передать `index` но это не работает

ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;
```

ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)Method1:(id)sender
{
    self.index = 1;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
}

-(IBAction)Method2:(id)sender

{
    self.index = 2;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

ViewController *dvc=[segue destinationViewController]; dvc.index = _index;

}


if (self.index == 2){
    _data1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],nil]
}

if (self.index == 2){
    _data2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],nil]
}
```

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController setIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faff1f18c30'`

Comment: а что если изменить в свойстве атрибут assign на strong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что у тебя в классе RootViewController нет переменной 
`index`, добавь ее, и будет тебе счастье. При этом сам способ работает именно так как ты ожидаешь

Comment: Проблема в том, что я использую `pageViewController`. `index` мне нужен чтобы регулировать контент в `ModelController` Может проще использовать `nsuserdefaults`? А то что-то запутался куда и что нужно передавать.

Comment: А класс RootViewController это что? Мог бы ты изменить код так, чтобы было понятно в каком классе что

Answer (score 0):

В методах Method1 и Method2 вручную грузишь контроллер, заполняешь его данными и вручную пушишь его в navigationController.

1) UIViewController *vc =
    [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewForPopover"];
2) vc.index = 1
3) [self.navigationController pushViewController: vc];

PS: может немного отличаться для разных ID и иерархий